# Error $ is not defined in Angular Universal

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-universal

I have this problem in Angular Universal

```
ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Does anyone know any way to solve it?

This is the part of code that fails

```
//some imports ...    
declare var $ : any; 

ngOnInit() {
     generateDirectory(){
            this.api.getCities('country_id='+3996063).subscribe(res => {
                $("#find").append("<ul class='findDir'>");
                for(let c in res){
                    $("#find>ul").append('<li><a href="/find/'+res[c].name.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase()+'">'+res[c].name+'</a></li>');
                }
                $("#find").append("</ul>");
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: no,no,no... why are you doing this? Don't manipulate the DOM like this, it's not the way to do it in angular.

Comment: yeah, you should use `*ngIf`, `{{value}}` etc in your template instead

Comment: The `ERROR ReferenceError` was a blessing in disguise. All other things aside, making several DOM operations to create the `<ul>` out of API call results, instead of compiling the template in one cycle, must be just about the worst way to do it performance-wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use jQuery when using Angular, really. Angular has all the tools to manipulate HTML the way you want it. This would be the correct way to do it Angular-way:

```
interface City {
    name: string;
}

class CitiesComponent implements OnInit {
    public cities$: Observable<City[]>;

    constructor(private readonly api: ApiClient) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cities$ = this.api.getCities(`country_id=3996063`);
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="findDir" *ngIf="(cities$ | async) as cities">
    <li *ngFor="let city of cities">
        <a [attr.href]="'/find/' + city.name.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase()">{{city.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I hope that I didn't leave any mistakes. But the idea is that you create a subscription of `cities$` which is of type `City[]`.

Then in template code you subscribe to it using `async` pipe and then iterate over list of cities using `*ngFor` directive

To do it even better, I'd advice again any kind of functions to be called from template and try to do as much as possible within your subscription, so that would be it:

```
interface City {
    name: string;
}

class CitiesComponent implements OnInit {
    public cities$: Observable<City[]>;

    constructor(private readonly api: ApiClient) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cities$ = this.api.getCities(`country_id=3996063`).pipe(
            map(cities => cities.map(city => ({
                    ...city,
                    url: city.name.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase()
                }))
            )
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="findDir" *ngIf="(cities$ | async) as cities">
    <li *ngFor="let city of cities">
        <a [attr.href]="city.url">{{city.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

as you can see, I do use map pipe operator to add `url` property to `Observable` instead of doing that in template. This is better practice.